# Which websites provides the packages that Ubuntu often used?

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, emacs, websites

Currently my Ubuntu server cannot reach external websites. I need provide a list of websites to the IT department that need to be whitelisted so that I can upgrade my Ubuntu packages via apt-get install/update/upgrade etc. Besides www.ubuntu.com, any other websites that provide commonly-used packages? Do those packages have a copy at ubuntu.com?

Related question, how can I find out where the Ubuntu package comes from? For example, I use apt-get install emacs to install emacs (currently blocked), how do I do where emacs package comes from?

If there is an existing list of useful websites, that would be great.
Thanks!
-tx

Comment: Here are the list http://mirrors.ubuntu.com/.

Comment: Thanks for the link. These are the mirror sites that provide the same content as ubuntu.com, right? I wonder if any other package providers that provide useful/commonly_used packages, for example emacs etc.

Answer (score 2):

If we are talking about APT repositories, then I can write the following.
I'm running Squid-Deb-Proxy with the following `/etc/squid-deb-proxy/mirror-dstdomain.acl.d/20-ubuntu` domain white list (see comments inside it) for APT repositories:

```
# ubuntu archives
archive.canonical.com
archive.ubuntu.com
us.archive.ubuntu.com
ports.ubuntu.com
security.ubuntu.com
ddebs.ubuntu.com
mirrors.ubuntu.com
ports.ubuntu.com
old-releases.ubuntu.com
archive.canonical.com
extras.ubuntu.com

# changelogs
changelogs.ubuntu.com

# launchpad personal package archives
ppa.launchpad.net
private-ppa.launchpad.net

# additional mirror domains
## Google - Chrome, Earth, etc.
dl.google.com

## Opera browser
deb.opera.com

## OpenSuse build service
download.opensuse.org

## UbuntuZilla
downloads.sourceforge.net

## VirtualBox
download.virtualbox.org

## R language
cloud.r-project.org

## Wine
dl.winehq.org

## Typora markdown editor
typora.io

## VLC
download.videolan.org

## Vivaldi browser
repo.vivaldi.com

## PlayOnLinux
deb.playonlinux.com

# Debian
httpredir.debian.org
deb.debian.org
security.debian.org
```

The full list of Ubuntu mirrors is available [on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors) and on http://mirrors.ubuntu.com/ .

About packages origin - you can use `apt-cache policy` command - see example output below:

```
$ apt-cache policy nano
nano:
  Installed: 2.5.3-2ubuntu2
  Candidate: 2.5.3-2ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 2.5.3-2ubuntu2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.5.3-2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Thanks first! Additional question on this: say this two sites: archive.ubuntu.com and us.archive.ubuntu.com, they both are ubuntu.com. If ubuntu.com is listed in the whitelist, would it cover those 2 (sub)sites?

Comment: They are mirrors with different IPs. If you say about wildcarding, then yes, they can be wildcarded in firewall/proxy filter with something like `.ubuntu.com`.